# Changing query param is not shown in the url

Tags: ember.js, ember-query-params

I want to click on a "export" button and transit to a route "home" with "export" query param set as true. I don't want this query param to refresh my route. So here is how my route looks like:

```
export default Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  queryParams: {
    export: {
      refreshModel: false
    }
  }
})
```

In my controller, i'm trying to observe the query param and call a function which does export for me and after that i want to set the query param back to null. here is my controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
const {Controller, inject} = Ember

export default Controller.extend({
  // == Dependencies ==========================================================
  session: inject.service(),
  // == Keyword Properties ====================================================
  queryParams: ['export'],
  export: null,

  queryParamsObserver: function () {
    if (this.get('export')) {
      this.exportFile()
      this.set('export', null)
    }
  }.observes('export'),

  // == Functions =============================================================
  exportFile () {
  },

  // == Actions ===============================================================
  actions: {
  }

})
```

But my problem is that when i set the query param to null, it won't change on the url. I'm wondering what i am missing here that is not causing that behavior.
Plus that i wonder if using observing query param is the best solution to trigger some actions.

Comment: So basically you want `export` to be always null, and just use it for linking to trigger the export?

Comment: well not always null, i want it to be set null when i initially transit to that route to be able to download the file. then set it null right after download. this export button i have is in application level and accessible from all the routes. so the user will be able to set export query param to true again by clicking on the export button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your case is related with the fact that your setting of `export` within controller is too early that query params change is not reflected to url. It is not trivial to learn about Ember.run loops. You should start learning about run loops by reading [following](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-ember-run-loop).

Take a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f5a4424b0b9f97a020bdcec7d07e7ec1?openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route), if you wrap the setting of `export` within `Ember.run.scheduleOnce` as in the twiddle then you will see `export` is cleared in the url. (In fact it is immediately removed; you never see it is becoming true; if you wrap both export function and clearing of `export` flag within a promise; let's say that will resolved after some seconds; then you will see it will become `true` then will be removed).

Regarding your question about using observers; I cannot see anything you could do with your current design. The reason is that; you are saying `refreshModel` is false; hence you do not have any hook methods available in route to trigger `export` function within controller if you are within the same route already. You need to change your design; what ykaragol suggested could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

First option, using a `service` and triggering the export via application route or via button component seems more applicable for your situation. You can use it from all of your routes. Users stay at the same route while they are exporting. I would use this option.

Second option is to convert the `exportFile` to a `thennable` function. When the exporting is finished, you can clear the queryParams. Here is [a working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9db2dab9ff2cd71eef9199f953981b03?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2Fmy-route) for you.